# @wire GetRecord for related field

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any way to bring back related fields from an object using the @wire GetRecord?  The below code works for the users email field but I can't get the user.contact.accountId back?  I've tried putting the USER_CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD in the field and optionalfiled secton.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  thanks

```
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id'; 
import USER_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.AccountId';
import USER_ACCOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Account.Name';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Email';

export default class CustomLookupExample extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

@track email;
@track AccountId;

@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: USER_ID,
    fields: [EMAIL_FIELD, USER_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD] })
  user;
    
  get Email(){
    console.log('here is email ' + getFieldValue(this.user.data, EMAIL_FIELD)); 
    return getFieldValue(this.user.data, EMAIL_FIELD);
  }
  get AccountId() {
    console.log('here is accountid ' + getFieldValue(this.user.data, USER_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD));
      return getFieldValue(this.user.data, USER_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the attribute like below

```
import USER_CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Contact.AccountId';
```

Also the user who is running the user has read access to Account and Contact object.
Since you are using the `USER_CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD`  in optional fields your code is not giving you any error but if the context/running user doesn't have access no value will be returned.

**Updated answer:-**
Below is slight changes to your code:-

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import {getRecord,getFieldValue} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id'; 
import USER_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.AccountId'; 
import USER_ACCOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Account.Name'; 
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Email';
import USER_CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Contact.AccountId';

export default class LwcGetRecord extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: USER_ID,
    fields: [EMAIL_FIELD], optionalFields: [USER_CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD,USER_ACCOUNT,USER_CONTACT] })
user;
    
  get Email(){
    console.log('here is it$$$$$ ' + getFieldValue(this.user.data, EMAIL_FIELD)); 
    return getFieldValue(this.user.data, EMAIL_FIELD);
  }
  get AccountId() {
    console.log('here is it$$$$$ ' + getFieldValue(this.user.data, USER_CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD));
      return getFieldValue(this.user.data, USER_CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD);
  }
  
}
```

**HTML Code:-**

```
<template>
     {Email}

      <br/>
     {AccountId}
</template>
```

However, you are supplying running user recordId to the getRecord. When you run this as system admin you won't get the account record details as system admin is not a community/portal user which will have an account or contact record linked to its user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I do have that import statement.  I am running this as system admin so I don't think its an access issue.  If I update the import statement to only change  the from to 'from @salesforce.com/Schema/User.Profile.Name'  I get a value.  I can create an apex query and return Contact.AccountId but for some reason this approach does not work.

Comment: For me the above import is working fine. Do check that `USER_ID` has value initialized when its passed in the @wire method and the user record id passed does have value in contact and account.

Comment: Thanks again for helping!  i updated my post to show exactly what I have in my code. I tweaked it a little to use the user.AccountId instead of user.contact.AccountId (since they seem to be the same thing) but sitll having issues.  The USER_ID is valid as the email is coming back but not the AccountId.  Thanks again!

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue.  It seems my second get is not working.  If I move the USER_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD into my getEmail.. the correct account ID gets captured.  So there appears to be something wrong with my getAccountId

Comment: @Fred:  I have made changes to the answer and gave a working code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, That did it!!!

Comment: I just realized that the only field that does not disply is the User.Account.Name.  The other fields do appear. Any idea why the User.Account.Name does not?  I can query it.  I don't see that when I look at fields in Workbench.  thanks!